# Connect 4 Diagonal Win Check

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I'm testing a diagonal win in a Ruby Connect 4 game. I have been using a hard-coded 2D array for testing:

```
grid_array = [
["B", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
[".", "B", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
[".", ".", "B", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
[".", ".", ".", "B", ".", ".", ".", "."],
[".", ".", ".", "X", "M", ".", ".", "."],
[".", ".", ".", ".", "X", "M", ".", "."],
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "X", "M", "."],
[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "X", "M"]
]
```

This inner loop of this method works correctly (correctly identifies that `'M'` or `'B'` separately are winners, but I am stuck when trying to move the diagonal checking across the columns or up the rows with the outer loop to pick up `'X'` as a winning value, for example.

```
def nw_diagonal_win (playing_board)
  row = 7
  while row < playing_board.size && row >= 0

    row = 7
    column = 7
    piece_count = 0

    while (row < playing_board.size && column < playing_board[row].size && column >= 0)

      if playing_board[row][column] == 'M'
        piece_count += 1

        if piece_count == 4
          puts "Player is the winner in a diagonal!"
        end

        puts piece_count.inspect

      else
        piece_count = 0
        puts "No winner."
      end

      row += 1
      column += 1
    end

    row -= 1
  end
end
```

Edited to add:
A 'winner' in Connect 4 sets 4 adjacent pieces (horizontal, vertical, or diagonal). In my game, this is represented by `'X'` and `'0'`. Pieces are "dropped" from the top of a column in the grid and fall to the bottom-most available space in that column. Pieces can be stacked in a column, but cannot "float" in the middle of the board. Diagonals may run from top left to bottom right or top right to bottom left. A win only occurs if pieces are uninterrupted within the grid (no wrapping around).

Think a larger version of tic-tac-toe where moves must be made in the bottom row first, and then can subsequently be made in the rows above, stacking like boxes. Four in a row (horizontal, vertical, or diagonal \ /) wins.

In response to answer suggestion from Steve, below:

```
def top_left_diagonal (playing_board, player_piece)
  row = 0
  while row < playing_board.size - 3
    piece_count = 0
    column = 0
    while column < playing_board[row].size - 3 && playing_board[row][column] == player_piece
      if (playing_board[row][column] == playing_board[row + piece_count][column + piece_count])
        piece_count += 1
      else
        piece_count = 0
      end
      column += 1
    end
    if piece_count == 4
      puts "Diagonal winner!"
    end
    row += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: For the element at location i,j let t=i-j. Then the element at location p,q is on the same main diagonal if and only if p-q=t. Varying t produces all main diagonals. Elements on each antediagonal have a similar property except `p+q=t`. Please define what constitutes a “winner”. Many readers, me included, have never heard of this game.

Comment: You should write function that counts points on a diagonal and then call that helper function for each of diagonal ( there are 2*(n+n-1) diagonals in n*n board - two directions and starting on each element of first row and first column)

Comment: @CarySwoveland https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four ... I'd expect it to be known everywhere... or at least unlimited paper variant of it.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I'll be back in the comments if I have any clarifying questions.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I understand the concept (column 7 - row 7) = 0, so all points on that diagonal are equal to 0 (4,4; 5,5, etc.,) I just don't understand how to implement that.

Comment: Sorry, but the Sandman beckons. I’ll post an answer in the morning if you don’t have a good one by then. In explaining the rules please indicate whether four in a row can “wrap around”. Also, please indicate whether winners can be on antediagonals (i.e., bottom left to top right).

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm working on it now, so we'll see...I'll leave a note, or add to my code if I figure something out.

Comment: This is a much better question than before.

Comment: @anothermh THANK YOU! I got super frustrated when you sent me that post to read, went and worked on my code for a while and came up with a solution for the initial (horizontal and vertical) wins. I appreciate the push. :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I confess I was born under a rock and haven't strayed far from it.

Comment: I suggest you move the description of the game to the top (no need for "Edited to add:") and make your code an answer rather than part of the question. (It's not uncommon for askers to offer solutions.) Best to keep the question just a question. You might refer to your answer in the question just to stem readers who miss your answer from asking what you've done to try to solve. My answer would be difficult for a newbie, but I think if you work at it, line-by-line, you'll understand it and learn a lot about both Ruby and the Ruby-way.

Comment: Will do, thanks @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 5):

Suppose we have

```
grid = [
  %w| . . . . . . |,
  %w| . . . w w . |,
  %w| . . . w b . |,
  %w| b . w . b . |,
  %w| w w . w b b |,
  %w| b w b b w b |
]
  #=> [[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."], 
  #    [".", ".", ".", "w", "w", "."],
  #    [".", ".", ".", "w", "b", "."],
  #    ["b", ".", "w", ".", "b", "."],
  #    ["w", "w", ".", "w", "b", "b"],
  #    ["b", "w", "b", "b", "w", "b"]]
```

True, this is is only 6x6, but the solution is no different.

Firstly, as the array is small we don't have to worry about computational efficiency, so we can concentrate on code efficiency.

Let's first check if there are four in a row in each row.

**Check the rows**

```
def four_in_a_row_by_row(arr)
  arr.each do |row|
    a = row.each_cons(4).find { |a| a.uniq.size == 1 && a.first != '.' }
    return a.first unless a.nil?        
  end
  nil
end
```

This method returns `w` if there are four `w`'s in a row, `b` if there are four `b`'s in a row, else `nil`.

For `arr = grid` we find that no row contains four `'b'`'s or `'w'`'s in a row.

```
four_in_a_row_by_row(grid)
  #=> nil
```

Note that this method does not require that `arr.size == grid.size` or that all elements of `arr` to be of the same size. It merely checks to see if any element has four `'w'`'s or four `'b'`'s in a row. This will have significance later.

The last element of `arr` passed to the block, for example, is the following.

```
row =  ["b", "w", "b", "b", "w", "b"]
```

We then compute

```
enum0 = row.each_cons(4)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["b", "w", "b", "b", "w", "b"]:each_cons(4)>
```

and

```
enum1 = enum0.find
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["b", "w", "b", "b", "w", "b"]:each_cons(4)>:find>
```

`enum1` can be thought of as a *compound* enumerator, though Ruby does not define it so. See [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) and [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find).

We can convert this enumerator to an array to see the elements that will be passed to the block.

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [["b", "w", "b", "b"],
  #    ["w", "b", "b", "w"],
  #    ["b", "b", "w", "b"]]
```

The first element is passed to the block and the following calculations are made.

```
    a = enum1.next
    u = a.uniq
    u.size == 1
```

We therefore do not need to compute `a.first != '.'`. The remaining two elements of `enum1` are passed to the block and `nil` is computed for each, indicating that there are not four in a row `'w'`'s or `'b'`'s in the last row.

We are almost finished!

"Wait", you say, we have only checked the rows! There are still the columns and all the diagonals! Stay tuned...

**Check the columns**

This one is dead-easy.

```
four_in_a_row_by_row(grid.transpose)
  #=> nil
```

Here

```
 grid.transpose
   #=> [[".", ".", ".", "b", "w", "b"],
   #    [".", ".", ".", ".", "w", "w"],
   #    [".", ".", ".", "w", ".", "b"],
   #    [".", "w", "w", ".", "w", "b"],
   #    [".", "w", "b", "b", "b", "w"],
   #    [".", ".", ".", ".", "b", "b"]]
```

**Check the diagonals (top left to bottom right)**

Here all we need do is construct as array `arr` containing the diagonals and then apply `four_in_a_row(arr)`. First identify the diagonals that include the elements in the first column that are of length `4` or greater. That includes the following diagonals

```
[grid[0][0], grid[1][1], grid[2][2], grid[3][3], grid[4][4],grid[5][5]] 
[grid[1][0], grid[2][1], grid[3][2], grid[4][3], grid[5][4]] 
[grid[2][0], grid[3][1], grid[4][2], grid[5][3]]
```

It is not necessary to consider the remaining diagonals that contain an element in the first column because they contain fewer than `4` elements:

```
[grid[3][0], grid[4][1], grid[5][2]] 
[grid[4][0], grid[5][1]] 
[grid[5][0]]
```

We can obtains the first three diagonals as follows.

```
(0..grid.size-4).map { |i| (0..grid.size-1-i).map { |j| grid[i+j][j] } }
  #=> [[".", ".", ".", ".", "b", "b"],
  #    [".", ".", "w", "w", "w"],
  #    [".", ".", ".", "b"]]
```

Similarly, identify the diagonals that include the elements in the first row, other that `grid[0][0]`, that are are of length `4` or greater. Those are the diagonals

```
[grid[0][1], grid[1][2], grid[2][3], grid[3][4], grid[4][5]] 
[grid[0][2], grid[1][3], grid[2][4], grid[3][5]]
```

The remaining diagonals containing an element in the first row (other than `grid[0][0]`) contain fewer than `4` elements. We obtain those diagonals as follows.

```
(1..grid.first.size-4).map do |j|
  (0..grid.size-j-1).map { |i| grid[i][j+i] }
end
  #=> [[".", ".", "w", "b", "b"],
  #    [".", "w", "b", "."]]
```

We therefore can obtain an array of all diagonals as follows.

```
def diagonals(grid)
  (0..grid.size-4).map do |i|
    (0..grid.size-1-i).map { |j| grid[i+j][j] }
  end.concat((1..grid.first.size-4).map do |j|
    (0..grid.size-j-1).map { |i| grid[i][j+i] }
  end)
end
```

```
arr = diagonals(grid)
  #=> [[".", ".", ".", ".", "b", "b"],
  #    [".", ".", "w", "w", "w"],
  #    [".", ".", ".", "b"],
  #    [".", ".", "w", "b", "b"],
  #    [".", "w", "b", "."]]
```

We see that no diagonals contain four in a row.

```
four_in_a_row_by_row(arr)
  #=> nil
```

**Check the antediagonals (botton left to top right)**

We could go through the same reasoning as in computing the diagonals, but since computational efficiency is not important here, there is an easier way: compute the diagonals of the array obtained by "rotating" `grid` 90 degrees.

```
def rotate90(grid)
  ncols = grid.first.size
  grid.each_index.with_object([]) do |i,a|
    a << ncols.times.map { |j| grid[j][ncols-1-i] }
  end
end
```

```
arr = rotate90(grid)
  #=> [[".", ".", ".", ".", "b", "b"],
  #    [".", "w", "b", "b", "b", "w"],
  #    [".", "w", "w", ".", "w", "b"],
  #    [".", ".", ".", "w", ".", "b"],
  #    [".", ".", ".", ".", "w", "w"],
  #    [".", ".", ".", "b", "w", "b"]]
arr1 = diagonals(arr)
  #=> [[".", "w", "w", "w", "w", "b"], [".", "w", ".", ".", "w"],
  #    [".", ".", ".", "b"], [".", "b", ".", ".", "w"], [".", "b", "w", "b"]]
```

We see that no antediagonals contain four in a row.

```
four_in_a_row_by_row(arr1)
  #=> "w"
```

**Putting it all together**

```
def four_in_a_row(grid)
  four_in_a_row_by_row(grid) ||
  four_in_a_row_by_row(grid.transpose) ||
  four_in_a_row_by_row(diagonals(grid)) ||
  four_in_a_row_by_row(diagonals(rotate90(grid)))
end
  
four_in_a_row_by_row(grid) 
  #=> "w"
```

**Alternative calculation of `four_in_a_row_by_row`**

One may alternatively write `four_in_a_row_by_row` as follows.

```
def four_in_a_row_by_row(arr)
  row = arr.find { |row| four_in_a_row(row) }
  row.nil? ? nil : four_in_a_row(row)
end
```

```
def four_in_a_row(row)
  (0..row.size-5).find { |j| row[j,4].uniq.size == 1 && row[j] != '.' }
end
```

```
four_in_a_row_by_row(grid)
  #=> nil
```

If preferred, `row.nil? ? nil : four_in_a_row(row)` could be replaced with

```
four_in_a_row(row) unless row.nil?
```

Comment: Thank you for the _super_ detailed explanation! I'm just learning Ruby, so some of this I don't quite understand, but what I can understand helped me to come up with a working *fingers crossed* solution.

I've added my solution as an answer to this post. I would appreciate any suggestions or hole-poking.

Comment: As always excellent answer from you.  For info, the physical toy "Connect4" requires that you insert your token in the top and gravity drops it to the lowest position.  So the dot in position [4][2] with the token in position [3][2] could never physically happen (unless, I guess, the token got "stuck" while falling, which I've never seen happen)

Comment: @Steve, thanks. Without looking I'll bet there's a youtube video showing a token getting stuck.

Comment: I had to check. Couldn't find one.  Curse my OCD.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was able to follow it up until the diagonals. The Map inside a Map confused me, would it be possible to breakdown `(0..grid.size-4).map { |i| (0..grid.size-1-i).map { |j| grid[i+j][j] } }` a little further?

Comment: @Christian, I did an edit to clarify my answer. Please let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks @Cary, I can understand the end result but it's getting there which is what I'm struggling with. `(0..grid.size-4)` resolves to `(0..2)`, what is `(0..2).map` actually doing?

Comment: `(0..2).map` returns an array of three elements, mappings of `0`, `1` and `2`. Consider, for example, `1`. `1` is passed to the block `{ |i| (0..grid.size-1-i).map { |j| grid[i+j][j] } }` and the block variable `i` is set to `1`. The block calculation for `i=1` is therefore `(0..grid.size-1-1).map { |j| grid[1+j][j] }`, which reduces to `(0..4).map { |j| grid[1+j][j] }`, which equals `[".", ".", "w", "w", "w"]`, so `i=1` is mapped to that 5-element array. Similar calculations are made for `i=0` and `i=2`. Clear?

Comment: that's great, appreciate you taking the time to write that. Between your answer and comments I am just about grasping it :)

Answer (score 1):

If there is a winning diagonal, the start position must be in the range of row [0-3] and col [0-3].  Any diagonal starting outside that upper left box wouldn't have enough right-and-down positions to make it to four in a row.

So really you need a `while row < 4` and `while col < 4` nested loops.

For each row col combination,  assuming that value is not "." you could then set your piece_count to 1 and then do a counter 1 to 3 and check `playing_board[row + counter][col + counter]` is equal to the value of `playing_board[row][col]` and if it is increment your piece_count.

Outside the counter 1 to 3 loop, if piece_count is 4, you have a winner.

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy, but I think I understand what you mean, Steve. I wrote some code and added it to the end of my question above. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: I added an answer below that I came up with. It starts at r7, c7 and moves from bottom right to top left. Do you see any immediate issues? I have been testing for a little bit and what I have come across, I've been able to address.

Comment: I think the code you added to the question won't work.  I don't think that column needs to be incremented if the piece count increases. But I see you have an answer from Cary and that's usually worth gold in the bank.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that has seemed to work in testing. It goes from bottom right to top left, starting at row 7, column 7 in my 8x8 grid. I've also created the antediagonal that moves from bottom left to top right.

I have tested for the last little while and haven't found an error, but would love to know if anyone else pokes holes in it.

I appreciate all of you so much -- your solutions and advice got me to this point!

```
def nw_diagonal_win (playing_board, player_piece)
    row = 7
    column = 7
    piece_count = 0
    while row < playing_board.size && row >= 0 && column < playing_board[row].size && column >= 0
      if playing_board[row][column] == player_piece
        piece_count += 1
        column -= 1
        row -= 1
      else
        piece_count = 0
        column -= 1
        if column < 3
          row -= 1
          column = 7
        end
      end
        if piece_count == 4
          puts "Player #{player_piece} is the winner in a diagonal!"
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with a similar grid, for a crosswords and come out with a way to get the diagonals. I changed a bit to fit the connect 4.
It is not a complete answer but I hope it can help.

First of all I want to map the grid to have also the coordinates:

```
grid_map = grid_array.map.with_index{ |line, y| line.map.map.with_index { |e, x| [e, x, y] } }
```

Then a couple of methods to recover all the diagonals of a matrix (there should be e better solution, anyway).

The first takes only half the diagonals in one direction:

```
def half_diagonals(matrix)
  max_y = matrix[0].size
  max_x = matrix.size
  diagonals = []
  (0...max_x).each do |x_start|
    x = x_start
    y = 0
    diagonal = [matrix[x][y]]
    while  x < max_x - 1 and y < max_y - 1 do
      x += 1
      y += 1
      diagonal << matrix[x][y]
    end
    diagonals << diagonal
  end
  # only in diagonals with at least four spots
  return diagonals.select{ |d| d.size >= 4 }
end
```

This calls half_diagonals(matrix) on transformations of the matrix to get all the diagonals:

```
def diagonals(matrix)
  half_diagonals(matrix) +
  half_diagonals(matrix.transpose)[1..-1] +
  half_diagonals(matrix.reverse) +
  half_diagonals(matrix.reverse.transpose)[1..-1]
end

# diagonals(grid_map).each { |e| p e } # to print the diagonals
```

Now, it is required to check each diagonal for a winner, so define a method to do so:

```
def check_diagonal(diagonal, empty_spot = ".")
  check = diagonal.chunk_while { |s1, s2| s1[0] == s2[0] }.map { |e| [e.count, e[0][0], e.map{ |ee| ee[1..-1]}] }
  return detected = check.detect { |e| e[0] == 4 and e[1] != empty_spot }
  # it returns the first four detected
end
```

Now call the methods on `grid_map`, to get the count, the colour and the coordinates of the connected four:

```
diagonals(grid_map).map { |diagonal| check_diagonal(diagonal) }.compact
#=> [[4, "B", [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]], [4, "X", [[3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7]]]]
```

The four `"M"` are not returned because of `check.detect`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm really interested in this solution, and will play with it more outside of this project!

Answer (score 0):

A neat way to retrieve those diagonals is to use `#rotate` on each row until the diagonals are lined up vertically, and then use `#transpose` to convert those columns to arrays.

The only catch is that you have to 'pad' each row with blanks before it's rotated -- otherwise, pieces on the edge will wrap around to the other side.

```
rows = [
  ["B", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
  [".", "B", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
  [".", ".", "B", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
  [".", ".", ".", "B", ".", ".", ".", "."],
  [".", ".", ".", "X", "M", ".", ".", "."],
  [".", ".", ".", ".", "X", "M", ".", "."],
  [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "X", "M", "."],
  [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "X", "M"]
]
  

def rotate_each(arr, shift, base)
  arr.map { |row| row.rotate(base += shift) }.transpose
end

def pad(rows, side = 'r', pad = ['.'] * 6)
  rows.map { |row| side == 'r' ? row + pad : pad + row }
end

def diagonals(rows)
  rotate_each(pad(rows), -1, 1) + rotate_each(pad(rows, 'l'), 1, -1)
end

diagonals(rows)
#=> [["B", "B", "B", "B", "M", "M", "M", "M"],
#    ...
#   ]
```